# Overflow menu layout lag

Tags: android, android-layout

When I'm opening the overflow menu, at first I see just an empty layout, and only after that the menu with text appears:

[image]

The same thing happens when the overflow menu is closing:

[image]

Creating this menu seems to be standard:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_bar_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_cp:
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        case R.id.action_used_libraries:
            return true;
        case R.id.action_help_and_feedback:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

why does it happen and how to get rid of this lag?

Comment: It seems that you have a first green menu area and then it create and animate it. Are you animating it in some manner?

Comment: @firegloves, no, I don't use animation here at all

Comment: yeah but it is animating your menu. search for that

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `<item name="android:background">@color/yourgreencolor</item>` from both your ThemeOverlay.AppTheme.ActionBar and ThemeOverlay.AppTheme.PopupMenu style, it's rendering a background first. I used `parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"` to have my desired white background, maybe that could help you find out how to have a green background despite this issue. It's definitively possible to have custom colors without this, I've seen some.